# awk command not working as expected when bash variable is used inside

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, cmd

I tried to use bash variable inside awk by creating a variable in awk command as below. but it does not work it seems

```
b=hi
$ echo "hihello" |awk -v myvar=$b -F"$0~myvar" '{print $2}'
```

**Actual Output is :**

```
<empty / nothing printed >
```

**Expected output is :**

> hello

Comment: why you included $0 in -F?

Comment: What is `-F"$0~myvar"`?

Comment: Use: `awk -v myvar=$b '$0 ~ myvar {print $2}'`

Comment: What sorcery is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```
b=hi ; echo "hihello" | awk -F"$b" '{print $2}'
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below awk command. Put the Field Separator inside BEGIN block.

```
$ b=hi; echo "hihello" | awk -v myvar=$b  'BEGIN{FS=myvar}{print $2}'
hello
```

It sets the value of myvar variable to the Field Separator. Thus inturn printing the second column will give you the string `hello`